# Can't gather tibble in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

Have you seen the newest problem with gathering `tibble` class with the use of `tidyr::gather` funciton? Now `dplyr` returns `tibble` after you use simple `select` or `rename` function on a `data.frame` .

Is there any way to workaround this instead of changing `tibble` class to `data.frame` ?

Simple example is below

```
> library(tibble)
> library(tidyr)
> 
> head(gather(iris, Species))
  Species      Species value
1  setosa Sepal.Length   5.1
2  setosa Sepal.Length   4.9
3  setosa Sepal.Length   4.7
4  setosa Sepal.Length   4.6
5  setosa Sepal.Length   5.0
6  setosa Sepal.Length   5.4
> 
> head(gather(as_tibble(iris), Species))
Error: Each variable must have a unique name.
Problem variables: 'Species'
> 
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=pl_PL.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=pl_PL.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=pl_PL.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=pl_PL.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=pl_PL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=pl_PL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] tidyr_0.6.0 tibble_1.2 

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] magrittr_1.5   assertthat_0.1 tools_3.3.1    Rcpp_0.12.6
```

Comment: Also posted here https://github.com/hadley/tidyr/issues/231

Comment: This is ridiculous as gather worked on 'tbl' as on 'data.frame' but with the newest release of dplyr it does not work on 'tibbles' with the similar syntax. I'll Have to rewrite many code Lines because of this incompatibility

Comment: @Axeman you can post your comment as and answer, please

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not necessarily with `tibble`. It is doing the safe (and arguably very restrictive) thing of not allowing duplicated column names.

This means your `gather` calls should avoid duplicated names. This can be achieved by supplying names for the `key` and `value` columns yourself, e.g.:

```
gather(iris, key, value, -Species)
```